# Are the releases from Mastercuts available on vinyl?

Tags: vinyl

I'm a music fan and I collect vinyl records. Lately I've been using discogs.com which is a very good site for buying records. But I want it on vinyl and for instance I want to buy the releases from Mastercuts that came in the 90s and those are listed as CD only and I don't see any seller listing them on vinyl. However I own a vinyl which is not listed on discogs and is labelled Mastercuts, it is Mastercuts disco which has a blue cover. are there more available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mastercuts was originally [Ian Dewhirst](http://www.djhistory.com/interviews/ian-dewhirst), DJ from the famous Leeds, UK club from the 80s - The Warehouse - arguably the first New York-style club in the UK (from where I actually knew him at the time, though haven't seen him in 20-odd years. There was an unknown cloakroom attendant there at the same time… [Marc Almond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marc_Almond))

The tracks were released through Beechwood. You might have some luck searching Discogs by that name too, but beware...

After Ian left Beechwood, there were still a few high-quality compilations released, but eventually they tailed off into CD-only & dodgy country & western back catalogue bargain-bucket supermarket shelf-fillers, so there's a limited time-period of quality releases. Beechwood went bust but the name was handed around to various companies over the years.

Rare Mastercuts vinyl from the 80s/90s now fetches up to $200 a disk, if you can find it.